# Unable to import libraries in python even though i have the libraries installed

Tags: python, pip

I can't import libraries in python that I have installed using `pip`
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbaVD.png).

Even other libraries such as PySimpleGui and PyGame don't work when I try to import them.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the libraries and I am sure they are installed on my computer.

Comment: Try restarting the IDE you are using. If it still doesn't work, just check if there are multiple versions of Python installed or whether you are using virtual environment.

Comment: How did you install them? The fact that they're underlined makes me think you're using an IDE that is using a different version/copy/virtualenv than where you did the installing.

Comment: It might be helpful if you comment on how you installed your packages with and what IDE you are using.

Comment: are you using vscode? if you are so, select the same python interpreter which you installed packages on.

Comment: Maybe confirm the venv your working with? You're probably using a different py version or venv in your IDE. Try this command which python to see what you are actively working with.

Comment: i just go into my windows terminal and "pip install <<library>>"

Comment: What does "don't work" or "I cannot import" mean? Do you get errors? Or its just the IDE showing a red underline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort this out, you need to establish two things:

- where you (i.e. `pip`) installed the packages, and
- where Python is looking for them

---

You can find where `pip` installed a package with:

```
pip show PACKAGE # e.g. pip show flask
```

Obviously, if you install using `pip3 install flask`, you will need to use:

```
pip3 show flask
```

---

Now you need to see which Python you are running and where it is looking for its packages:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable) # show which Python we are running
print(sys.path)       # show where it is looking for packages
```

---

Hopefully you will see you are not installing into the Python interpreter you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have installed them under a different folder or space than what you need. For example the code below installs the library at your current space, while simply `pip3 install pygame` might be somewhere else.

```
python3 -m pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: it says "No module named pip3"

Comment: well you gotta install pip3 first either from brew or download python