# No module named 'PIL' after Installing pillow latest version

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I am installed pillow,following the documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#),

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

and import Image like this:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Even though I upgraded  Pillow  to   9.4.0, I am getting the following error in vscode

> No module named 'PIL'

I am using Python 3.9.7. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, is it my python version or is it the vscode. Can someone please enlighten me about this issue.

I can see them installed in my venv folder, but cannot access it in the file I am working on (which is highlighted by yellow)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Comment: No I followed that exact method but still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one python installation? Are you sure you run the code with the import with same python interpreter for which Pillow is installed?

Comment: Yes I created my virtualenv using python3..9 -m venv venv. and thats where I have all the libraries installed. I can see them in the folder but for some reason cannot access it

Comment: Can you access other libraries inside the same virtual environment?

Comment: yeah I need 2 libs basically which are numpy as PIL, and I access numpy

Comment: Is this for RaspberryPi? I remember having a very similar problem some time ago but can't recall the exact issue and solution. I only remember it was highly coupled to the fact that the setup was for an RPi... I think it was something like you had to install the basic library from APT package manager or something like this (sorry I don't remember exactly) :-(

Comment: No its for this OOP course on udemy https://www.udemy.com/course/the-python-pro-course/learn/lecture/23827460#learning-tools

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277279/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your script.

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Ensure that your sys.path contains the path "$PROJECT/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages"

If it doesn't, your virtual environment is **broken**. Try this instead:

- Use this command to remove the current environment. `rm -rf venv`
- Create it again. `python -m venv venv`
- Install all your dependencies and run `pip install --no-cache-dir Pillow`

Make sure your environment is functioning properly right now.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have also problems with vscode venv because they dont get which packages are installed ...

if you have installed the package in the venv and selected the venc (`source .venv/bin/active`) there should be no problem running it. It only seems to be a linter problem.

By using my system python installation interpreter and have installed the packages there I dont get the error