# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pil' even when the module was installed in vsc

Tags: python-imaging-library

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\python project\first project\hello.py", line 2, in 
from pil import image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pil'

The pip pillow istall

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277279/2836621

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.