# Can't install PIL package

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've done all I could and found on the internet. I need to download Pillow. I ran `pip install Pillow` in the PyCharm terminal and after checking, it is indeed installed but when I try to use it in my code, it can't seem to recognise it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was working with tkinter and have recently started programming python so I'm a newbie. I came across a problem relating to images and learned that I should try PIL. When I hover over PIL in my code and try to install it(even though it already is as per terminal) I get an error. would be grateful for the help :D

Comment: make sure that you have pip installed to the same version that you are running.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277279/2836621

Comment: So, why are you trying to install it if it is already installed?  Does the code run?

Comment: The name used in `pip install` is `pillow`, i.e. `pip install pillow`.

Comment: looks like you installed Pillow into a virtual environment (notice one path includes `pomodoro-start/venv`) but maybe you're not using that virtual environment in your editor.  it's probably better to install the package into the virtual environment used by your editor, rather than one that was incidentally created in your downloads. working in your downloads directory could work, but will add complications that probably aren't worth it if you're learning

Comment: @acw1668 packages installed via PyPI are case insensitive, so it shouldn't matter whether OP runs `pip install Pillow` or even `pip install pIlLoW`.  see https://stackoverflow.com/q/26503509/1358308

Comment: Please do not post ***pictures*** of code. They are impossible to search, or run. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

When you ran:

```
pip show pillow
```

it tells you that it installed Pillow in a *"venv"* somewhere under your home directory, i.e. `/Users/raza/Downloads/pomodoro-start/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages`. That means the Python in that `venv` will look there for packages.

---

When you ran Python, in your IDE, it told you that it is running the Python interpreter under `/System/Library` somewhere, specifically at  `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3`. That Python interpreter will look in directory very close to that for its packages.

You can equally see this information if you run:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable) # show which Python we are running
print(sys.path)       # show where it is looking for packages
```

So, in conclusion you are installing Pillow in location A (a `venv` in `/Users/raza/...`) but your Python interpreter in PyCharm is looking for it in Location B (`/System/Library/...`).

---

In order to fix it, you have a couple of options:

- either install Pillow to the place where your Python is looking, or
- tell your IDE to use the Python where you installed Pillow.

---

So, for the first option above...

Your IDE is using Python at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3`, so if you want to install Pillow for that interpreter, use:

```
# Install Pillow
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install Pillow

# Check where it was installed
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip show pillow
```

---

For the second option, (I don't know or use PyCharm), you need to go somewhere in the settings of PyCharm and tell it to use the Python interpreter at `/Users/raza/Downloads/pomodoro-start/venv/lib/python3.10` or nearby.