# PIL not working on Python 3.12, even though it's installed, and up to date, and works on Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've upgraded from Python 3.8 32 bit to 3.12 64 bit because of memory limitations. However, the module PIL isn't being recognised, with this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\rhann\Desktop\Scripts\langton's ant.py", line 2, in <module> from PIL import Image ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`

The version of Pillow is 10.2.0, and I installed it using the command `pip3 install Pillow` on the command line.
The line causing the error is `from PIL import Image`. The line before it, `import math`, does not cause problems.

I've looked up questions on this website, and some others, but none of them have helped. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow.

Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Each copy of Python has its own libraries; whether you have something installed for Python 3.8 and have it installed for Python 3.12 are _completely_ unrelated. Similarly, a single invocation of `pip3` only installs for _one_ Python 3.x interpreter, not _every_ Python 3.x interpreter.

Comment: Do you have Pillow installed for the same Python version you are running your code with?

Comment: `py -3.12 -m pip install Pillow` may be your friend here (untested, though -- I don't run Windows, and py.exe is a Windows-only thing). Just `pip3` doesn't specify a particular version.

Comment: Charles Duffy, that worked. How do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: I'll add it as a proper answer; once that's done there will be a checkbox you can click.

Comment: If you do `pip show pillow` it will tell you **where** you installed it and for **which** Python. More explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77598579/2836621

Comment: Oops, forgot to answer it last night. Doing that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each version of Python (and each virtualenv) has a separate set of installed packages -- so just running `pip3` will install a package for *one* Python 3.x environment (usually, but not always, the same one that `python3` will start an interpreter for), not *every* Python 3.x environment.

As an alternative to invoking `pip3` via its command wrapper, you can invoke pip *as a module* within the specific interpreter you want it to install a package for; that way it doesn't matter which interpreter's copy of `pip3` comes first in your PATH.

---

Installing Pillow for Python 3.12 on Windows this way might look like:

```
py -3.12 -m pip install Pillow
```

On more UNIX-y systems, this might instead be `python3.12 -m pip install Pillow`.